# Text on Image stays in place despite image resizing

Tags: css, html, resize, font-size

I made a quick web design which has three images.

As the browser size decreases, so do the pictures, so they all stay in visible sight.

Now I tried to put text over those images, but the text moves around with the browser resizing.

Basically, I want the text to always stay in one spot on the picture, as the picture sizes decrease.

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JwGuR/

You will notice the text is not even on the image because the window is fairly small. Try making the window bigger, and the text will go onto the images. I want the text to stay in place despite the browser size.

Here is the CSS for the text:

```
.imgText {
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 250px 0 0 200px; 
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working in FF.

Comment: The automatic image resizing isn't working in FF though. Take a look at the JSFiddle. I want the images to resize based on browser size, which they do. Now I need the text to do the same.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for pointing that out. That still doesn't fix my problem though. EDIT: Seeing your new answer now.

Comment: @MrLister I tried putting each image with text in their own separate div, but for some reason it messed up the website by setting the images vertically instead of how they currently are, horizontally. I assume that's what you mean by putting them in the same element?

Comment: It looks great. Does this only work in browsers that support HTML5? Also, is there a way to make a point where the browser just starts to caves in on the images on slowly covers them. Because eventually they shrink to to small of a point, where the text looks out of place.

Comment: No, I didn't use any HTML5, so that's OK. But as far as I know, there is no property that restricts the max width to a minimum max width. Ehm, that would be min-max-width. No. You could do something with a media query of course...

Comment: @MrLister What is I wanted the text to be vertically centered on the image. Final question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/JwGuR/10/

```
<div class="figure">
    <div class="figcaption">Text1</div>
    <img src="path/to/image">
</div>
```

(or you can use real HTML5 and use actual `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements.)

The CSS:

```
.figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 33%;
}

.figure .figcaption {
    text-align: center; 
    width:100%; height:0;
    font-size: 25px; line-height: 0;
    color:white;
    position:absolute; top:50%;
    z-index:1;
}

.figure img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

You can also lose the whitespace between the images if you want, by giving the `.figure` elements a `float:left`. (and doing a `clear` after).